# I'm trying to create a live search bar on my webpage but can't seem to make it work. It just doesn't display any data

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, livesearch

The template.php file contains all the coding related to the script.

```
<?php
include 'dbh.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
        <link rel ='Stylesheet' type ='text/css' href ='Styles/StyleSheet.css'/>

    </head>
    <body>

            <div id="banner">

            </div>
            <form action="">
                <input type ="text" id="search">

            </form>
        <div id="result">

        </div>
            <div id="content_area">
                <?php echo $content; ?>

            </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $('#search').keyup(function()
            {
                var search = $('#search').val();
                if($.trim(search.length)==0)
                {
                    $('#result').html('Please enter correct data');
                }
                else
                {
                    $.ajax({
                                type:'POST',
                                url:'Search.php',
                                data:{'search':search},
                                success:function(data)
                                {
                                   $('#result').html(data); 
                                }
                            });
                }
            })
        })


        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

The Search.php file contains the code related to query of data. My database has only one table named CINFO and has only one column named Title.

```
<?php
include 'dbh.php';
if(isset($_POST['search']))
{
   $search = $_POST['search'];
   $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * from CINFO where TITLE LIKE ?");
   $query->execute(["%$search%"]);
   $count = $query->rowCount();
   if($count==0)
   {
       echo "Sorry No result found";
   }
   else
   {

       while($r = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
       {
           $name = $r->Title;
           echo "$name";
       }
   }
}

?>
```

dbh.php has code related to the connection of the database-

```
<?php
$server = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "ComicDB";
$conn = mysqli_connect($server, $username, $password,$dbname);
?>
```

Whenever I enter any data in the search box, all it doesn't display any data but when I press backspace and delete what I've entered it does display 'Please enter correct data' which means the if block in template.php is getting executed but not the else block. Thats what I've understood out of the code. Can't seem to figure out what I've done wrong.

Comment: You should be using JSON to pass data from the server to the client: right now you are only echoing plain text. When iterating through your results, push them to an array and then echo the array using `json_encode()`. There are multiple possible points of failure: check your browser's network tab. Are you calling `Search.php` are the correct URL? What is the HTTP status code returned?

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your `ajax` call. Have you checked the browser dev tools to check ajax is posting to your php file or for error reports in the console?

Comment: NewTOJS How to check it? I'm using safari on macos.

Comment: I believe you can access the console using the following shortcut:  **`Option`** + **`Cmd`** & **`C`** If you don't see the Develop menu, you'll need to turn it on using Safari Preferences. **Open Safari** > **Preferences**, and click on the **Advanced Tab**.

Comment: Thanks a tonne NewTOJS. I just figured it out. It was an issue with how I was calling the ajax. Its working fine now.